# Find list<T> item by searching for combination of keys C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to find the department assigned to an employee on a particular date using List. 
Combination of employeeID and date will be unique meaning an employee will be assigned to only one department on a particular date.

```
List<clsEmployee> _items = new List<clsEmployee>();

_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=100,Date="05/05/2017",DeptAssigned="Grocery"});
_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=100,Date="06/05/2017",DeptAssigned="Clothing"});
_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=100,Date="07/05/2017",DeptAssigned="Crockery"});

_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=101,Date="05/05/2017",DeptAssigned="cosmetics"});
_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=101,Date="06/05/2017",DeptAssigned="gardening"});
_items.Add(new clsEmployee() 
{EmpId=101,Date="07/05/2017",DeptAssigned="grocery"});


  clsEmployee objEmployee = new clsEmployee ();
  objEmployee = _items.Find(x => x.EmpId == 100);
//i want something like objEmployee = _items.Find(x => x.EmpId==100 
 //&& x => x.Date="05/05/2017");
string DeptAssignedToEmp = objEmployee.DeptAssigned;
//expected result - grocery in this case.
```

Comment: As a side note - just a suggestion:
You will be safer having DeptAssigned not as a simple string. Use at least some sort of constants, even better enum.

This way you would avoid issues with typos and case sensitive comparisons

Comment: Do not use strings to represent dates

Comment: It looks like you have asked many questions without accepting any while you got many good answers!! Please feel free to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/Tour) to check how to accept correct answers.

Answer (score 6):

Simple, use `&&` without another `x =>`

```
clsEmployee objEmployee = _items.Find(x => x.EmpId == 100 && x.Date == "05/05/2017");
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
clsEmployee objEmployee = _items.FirstOrdefault(x => x.EmpId == 100 && x.Date == "05/05/2017");
```

Side-note: don't use strings for a Date-property but `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`Find` may not be the most suitable to use, since in theory there could be more items that match your critaria. perhaps you should consider using `Where`

```
var matchingItems = _items.Where(x => x.EmpId==100 && x.Date=="05/05/2017");
```

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, since there could be more items in the set that match your criteria.

You could use `FirstOrDefault`, which will return `null` if no matching items were in the collection, but otherwise will return the first object in the collection.

```
var matchingItem = _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpId==100 && x.Date=="05/05/2017");
if(matchingItem == null)
{
    //nothing matched your criteria
}
```

Comment: Lol i should be careful when copy pasting out of the original question

Comment: Why `Where` followed by a `FirstOrDefault`? why not `FirstOrDefault` alone?

Comment: You can just do `FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpId==100 && x.Date=="05/05/2017")` instead.

Comment: `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` can be condensed into `FirstOrDefault`. You're also missing () after the `FirstOrDefault` call. And you have reverted my edit, you need to use `==` for comparison, not `=` (which you are using when comparing the date)

Comment: You could even go with `SingleOrDefault` since the searched combination is supposed to be unique. I guess it depends on how the OP wants his application to react in the case of unexpected data